# Setting image transparency using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

How do I set image transparency with Leaflet so that i can see through to google basemap

```
function imageStyle(){

        return{ opacity:0.5,}   
                }       
var imageBounds=[
 [-22.0,22.5],
 [-26.18,25.452]
 ]
var imageLayer=L.imageOverlay(imageUrl,imageBounds).addTo(map);
//imageLayer.setOpacity( 0.5);
```